# FastBaps producing same output as example

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have downloaded the genetic clustering code FastBaps from https://github.com/gtonkinhill/fastbaps

I followed the instructions on this website very closely from the "introduction" section of ReadMe, but the first figure that gets produced is identical the figure posted on github. I thought that all I needed to do was swap out the fasta file with my own, which I did with "ny_ct_2.fa"

[this is a screenshot of what I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIY21.png)

I have attached a photo of the code I wrote in RStudio and I would appreciate if anyone could tell me how to fix this bug. Thanks.

Comment: Please don’t post screenshots of your code — post your *actual code*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You imported the same file as the example.

```
fasta.file.name <- system.file("extdata", "seqs.fa", package = "fastbaps")
# etc...
```

To import your file do:

```
fasta.file.name <- "/Users/schuylersloman/Documents/CODE/BIO_LAB/SENIOR_YEAR/ny_ct_2.fa"
sparse.data <- import_fasta_sparse_nt(fasta.file.name)
# etc...
```

Comment: Thanks so much! But now I am getting a "cannot find file" error. Specifically it says > fasta.file.name <- system.file("extdata", "/Users/schuylersloman/Documents/CODE/BIO_LAB/SENIOR_YEAR/ny_ct_2.fa", package = "fastbaps")
> sparse.data <- import_fasta_sparse_nt(fasta.file.name)
     Error in import_fasta_sparse_nt(fasta.file.name) : Can't locate file ................... (I also tried just doing the file name and got the same issue)

Comment: @Schuyler2000 You have to enter a valid path to the file. Ideally start R in the folder where your file sits. In a running R you can type `getwd()` and navigate to your file from there. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: @Schuyler2000 The file probably does sit in your user space, so the above edit should work.

Comment: Okay this makes a lot of sense @AndreWildberg. I am new to R and RStudio, but I see that RStudio is in "/Users/schuylersloman" and my file is in "/Users/schuylersloman/Documents/CODE/BIO_LAB/SENIOR_YEAR/ny_ct_2.fa" .... I've tried writing fasta.file.name <- system.file("extdata", "/Documents/CODE/BIO_LAB/SENIOR_YEAR/ny_ct_2.fa", package = "fastbaps") .... but I get the same error. Any chance you know what exactly I should write

Comment: @Schuyler2000 Leave out the `system.file...`. Copying the lines in my example should work.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much this has been so helpful! I really appreciate it